# Obtener datos de un array de objetos json

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, rest

Hola estoy tratando de obtener los datos de un array de objetos json y guardarlos en un arrays de javascript distintos

Por ejemplos obtengo este JSON atraves de una api rest

```
[
    {
        "temperatura": 2.3,
        "fecha": "2018-02-05T06:13:01.000Z"
    },
    {
        "temperatura": 2.3,
        "fecha": "2018-02-05T06:50:45.000Z"
    },
    {
        "temperatura": 2.3,
        "fecha": "2018-02-05T06:52:14.000Z"
    },
    {
        "temperatura": 29,
        "fecha": "2018-02-05T06:59:37.000Z"
    },
    {
        "temperatura": 30,
        "fecha": "2018-02-05T07:19:36.000Z"
    }
]
```

Quisiera poder guardar las temperaturas en un array y las fechas en otro array distinto

Quise hacer esto

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var processed_json = new Array();
            var fechas = new Array();
            $.getJSON('https://secure-brushlands-10563.herokuapp.com/sensors/temperaturas', function (json) {
                // Populate series
                console.log(json);

                for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    $.each(json[i], function (index, data) {
                        processed_json.push(data);
                    });
                }

                console.log(processed_json);
                console.log(typeof(processed_json));
```

Y obtengo esto

```
    Array [ 2.3, "2018-02-05T05:46:29.000Z", 2.3, "2018-02-05T06:13:01.000Z", 2.3, "2018-02-05T06:50:45.000Z", 2.3, "2018-02-05T06:52:14.000Z", 29, "2018-02-05T06:59:37.000Z", … ]
object
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba ejecutando un `$.each()` para obtener el resultado del `json`, obtienes la "clave" y el "valor" y lo agregas al array correspondiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temperaturas = new Array();
    var fechas = new Array();
    $.getJSON('https://secure-brushlands-10563.herokuapp.com/sensors/temperaturas', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            temperaturas.push(val.temperatura);
            fechas.push(val.fecha);
        })
    });
    console.log(temperaturas);
    console.log(fechas);
});
```

Comment: Es esto! Muchas gracias!!